# Mysql and php correct way to output data

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am working with PHP and MySQL, this is just a simple example of what I need.
I want to collect data as is shown in the last table. Combine data from all 3 tables.

What is the right way to print them as they are in the last table on the image instead of having every record as a new row after joining tables?
Should I use subquery somehow or 1st loop through "users" and for each user 2nd loop through "discipline" and then 3rd loop through "fight" and print out wins for each fight of each user?
Data does not have to be exactly printed as shown, just to have in the output table for each user, total number of wins with each discipline sorted by total number of wins (sorting is working already).

Many thanks in advance.

db structure:

[image: db structure]

I was able to get results but looping 3 times. I am hoping there is a better, cleaner solution.

Comment: You need to learn about joins in sql

Comment: Joins are not a problem, I know what they are and how they work. I can join and have all the data in the output. My question is more related to the output of how to group by users and still have all other data for all different disciplines and wins.

Comment: I think you need to group by user and by discipline, and count the number of wins. If you only group by users you will only get one row per user, and you will be forced to use things like GROUP_CONCAT to retrieve the data which is not optimal

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question is not correctly formulated. In this case, I will still have 2 records for user Mark after joining and grouping by both fields. In the output how to print only once his username and then print all his fights? Maybe is now a little clearer what I am looking for. This is more PHP/HTML formatting output question.

Comment: `My question is not correctly formulated`...in that case please [edit] it. Provide all clarification in the original post please, don't hide it in disparate comments out of context. It's not a discussion forum :-). (See also the [tour] and [ask].). And it would _really really_ help us all to understand your requirements clearly if you could show your existing code and explain what you don't like about it.

Comment: What you are looking for, is called a [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break). You need to compare the value of your break criterion (here, the user) of the current record, with that of the previous one - and then create the appropriate output, based on the result.